# NameError when functions from outside the main file that imports all other functions are called (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a text-based game, and I just finished the majority of code, and now the only thing I have to write is game content.

However, what I have now is mostly broken. Everytime I run [this file](http://pastebin.com/iud72rPt) with these four files: [this](http://pastebin.com/j6RgdHsw), [this](http://pastebin.com/WDdDfPAA), and [this](http://pastebin.com/LrETC0sZ) file, it crashes when I enter 'play' or 'story' it gives "NameError: Global name 'gameF' not defined" and "NameError: Global name 'storyF' not defined", respectively.

I have tried Googling 'Global name' and 'NameError', but I found nothing useful or that I could understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the function from the file where it was defined. If `gameF()` is defined in my_file.py, you just need to do:

```
from my_file import gameF
```

Comment: @JoelCornett No, `import *` is [almost never a good idea](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import).

Comment: @delnan I think in this case, it's a pretty safe bet, considering he wrote the module himself. The page you posted refers to importing from builtins, and, more generally from 3rd party modules. I believe  this is neither.

Comment: @JoelCornett Trust me, the same issues apply to one's own code. I once did `import *` to my heart's content among my modules, and a few weeks later I was forced to clean up and remove all those imports, as they hurt readability.

Comment: @delnan Ah, I see. Thanks for the link btw. I read the whole thing.

Comment: So you import functions instead of entire python modules? Interesting, didn't know that. Thanks for the help, will try implementing this to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function named `gameF()` or others, you have two possibilities:

- Define them into the same file where you recall (in this case menu.py)
- Include them at the top of the file

So, where are you defing these functions?

**Edit** I just noticed that you include something like `game,consolle and story`. If `gameF` is defined in `game`, you have to recall it in that way: `game.gameF()` or, much simple, try to type: `from game import gameF` and use it in a "normal" way